В каком разрешении делать картинки для смартфонов?
Делаю приложение для смартфонов на Android с помощью framework KivyMD на python при этом хочу отрисовать собственные арты для приложения. Я ещё начинающий и хотелось бы узнать в каком разрешении мне необходимо рисовать картинки? Я так понимаю ширина смартфонов в принципе небольшая и мне кажется, что сделать что-то вроде 800х600 оптимально и для более маленьких устройств уменьшать. На планшеты не планирую.
Хотелось бы услышать мнение специалистов в каком разрешении рисовать? Не хотелось бы тратить много времени на большие изображения, которые итак будут уменьшены автоматически для смартфона.

Может быть вариантик: 400х225?

Примерно ни в каком из реальных кейсов не нужно делать андроид приложение на питоне

Я согласен с комментарием выше, каждый ЯП предназначен для своих задач и боюсь создание полноценных приложений под андроид в область задач питона не входит. Посмотрите в сторону Kotlin или Java, они уже имеют огромную кодовую базу где вы наверняка сможете найти то, что вам нужно. Что касается вашего вопроса, то поэкспериментируйте с изображениями: создайте маленькое тестовое изображение и постепенно увеличивайте его до тех пор пока результат вас не удовлетворит.
